# Push Notification for web app giving Manifest empty or missing error

Tags: java, jsp, google-chrome, web-applications, push-notification

> Push Notifications on localhost is unable to access manifest.json.

Followed the steps from https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/push-notifications/

My manifest.json contents (hidden project number)

```
"name": "xyz",  
  "short_name": "x",  
  "icons": [{  
        "src": "images/icon_add.gif",  
        "sizes": "192x192",
        "type": "image/gif"
      }],  
  "start_url": "my_link",  
  "display": "standalone",  
  "gcm_sender_id": "my_app_id",
  "gcm_user_visible_only": true
```

> NOTE

- manifest.json is at root.
- Link to manifest.jason is at start of the `<head>`.
- `<head>` is at start/first element of index.jsp

index.jsp

```
<head>
 <link rel="manifest"  href="/manifest.json"/> 
 <script src="javascript/main.js"></script>
 .....
```

web.xml

```
<web-app id="XYZ">
 <display-name>XYZ</display-name>
.....   
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Opened`localhost:8080/XYZ/index.htm` and popup notification doesn't work with below error from console.

[image: Error]

Tried below:

- Changed `type attribute` of `link` tag.
- Moved `link` and `script` tags to top of `head` tag of index.jsp.

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you already resolved it. But if you didn't, try `<link rel="manifest"  href="manifest.json"/>`  instead of `/manifest.json`.